# merge_sort in python

Tags: python, mergesort

I am new to python and am trying to implement merge_sort in Python, here is my code. But it gets into infinite loop. Can anyone point out why? Thanks

```
def merge_sort(a):
    '''implement merge sort for array'''
    l = len(a)
    if l == 1:
        return a[0]
    a1 = merge_sort(a[:l/2-1])
    a2 = merge_sort(a[l/2:-1])
    a_sort = []
    idx1, idx2 = 0, 0
    #for i in range(l):
    if idx1 == len(a1):
        a_sort.append(a2[idx2:])
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        return a_sort
    elif idx2 == len(a2):
        a_sort.append(a1[idx1:])
        return a_sort
    else:      
        if a1[idx1] >= a2[idx2]:
            a_sort.append(a2[idx2])
            idx2 += 1
        else:
            a_sort.append(a1[idx1])
            idx1 += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your recursion gets down to an empty list (ie `l == 0`), you call `merge_sort([])` twice before you return anything. You need to add a check that `if l == 0: return []`.

Also, your check for `if l == 1: return a[0]` is a little bit wrong; `merge_sort` should always return a list, whereas this is returning a list element (a number or a string or whatever). So it should probably just be

```
if l <= 1:
    return a
```

Plus, your `a2` actually doesn't include the last element of the array: you want `a[l/2:]`, not `a[l/2:-1]`. (Remember that ranges in Python **don't** include the last element.)

This doesn't affect the correctness of the code, but you should be using `l // 2` to mean integer division; in Python3 or if you do `from __future__ import division`, `l/2` would be a float if `l` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

As Dougal and Andrei pointed out, the infinite loop is caused by unchecked edge condition. Replace the line `if l == 1:` w/ `if l < 2:`.
There are other issues in the code as well:

- left part and right part of list `a` by position `l/2` are corresponding `a[:l/2]` and `a[l/2:]`. There is not need to minus 1. Just think that a position is between two items.
- Use `.extend()` instead of `append()` in the `if` and `elif` branches
- Don't forget to get the commented-out forloop back.
- There is no `return` at last

And normally a `while` structure is more convenient

```
while idx1 < len(a1) and idx2 < len(a2):
    'code in your else branch'    
if idx1 < len(a1):
    a_sort.extend(a1[idx1:])
else:
    a_sort.extend(a2[idx2:])
return a_sort
```

Comment: def merge_sort(a):
    '''implement merge sort for array'''
    l = len(a)
    if l == 1:
        return a
    a1 = merge_sort(a[:l//2])
    a2 = merge_sort(a[l//2:])
    a_sort = []
    idx1, idx2 = 0, 0
    while idx1 < len(a1) and idx2 < len(a2):
        if a1[idx1] >= a2[idx2]:
            a_sort.append(a2[idx2])
            idx2 += 1
        else:
            a_sort.append(a1[idx1])
            idx1 += 1
    if idx1 < len(a1):
        a_sort.extend(a1[idx1:])
    else:
        a_sort.extend(a2[idx2:])
    return a_sort

Comment: @user1334179 what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Working code as below

```
def merge_sort(a):
'''implement merge sort for array'''
l = len(a)
if l == 1:
    return a
a1 = merge_sort(a[:l//2])
a2 = merge_sort(a[l//2:])
a_sort = []
idx1, idx2 = 0, 0
while idx1 < len(a1) and idx2 < len(a2):
    if a1[idx1] >= a2[idx2]:
        a_sort.append(a2[idx2])
        idx2 += 1
    else:
        a_sort.append(a1[idx1])
        idx1 += 1
if idx1 < len(a1):
    a_sort.extend(a1[idx1:])
else:
    a_sort.extend(a2[idx2:])
return a_sort
```

Comment: still has problem w/ `a = []` for example